# Jade template engine, rendering HTML as text

Tags: node.js, pug

I have this piece of code in one of my `.jade` files:

```
each item in items
  li= item.name + " " + item.inStock + " <a href='/item/"+item.uniqueId+"'>buy now!</a>"
```

What this renders is:

```
Of Mice and Men 1000 <a href='/item/1'>buy now!</a>
[...]
```

As you can see the `<a href='/item/1'>buy now!</a>` is not rendered as HTML but as plain text. Is there a way to render it as HTML, so that it creates a link?

Thanks!

Comment: No... If you read the whole question before posting you would have spotted the part where I say "As you can see the `<a href='/item/1'>buy now!</a>` is not rendered as HTML but as plain text."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
each item in items
  li
   | #{item.name} #{item.inStock}
   a(href="/item/"+item.uniqueId) buy now!
```

Comment: Even better, removes the security issues of `!=`. (edited for typo)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. May I ask where did you find this info, except from experience? I tried to look on the Jade main page but very little info is given on how to treat variables passed from Express. Maybe if you explain me how this works it would be clearer, since I still have no idea.

Comment: For the !=, it's on the github page's readme: " Code buffered by = is escaped by default for security, however to output unescaped return values you may use !=". wtfcoder's solution (if I may speak on his behalf!) is from experience and good use of the template engine's feature. He renders the anchor using jade's syntax, instead of in a string treated as javascript code.

Comment: It uses the Tag Text support with interpolation, followed by nested tags. It is somewhat listed on the readme on https://github.com/visionmedia/jade, however I agree the examples could be better/clearer, I've been using Jade for nearly a year so I've experimented a lot. It gives no special behavior to Express in terms of rendering, in that the same result can be observed with j=require('jade');tmpl=j.compile(templateStr);output=tmpl(templateData)

Answer (score 4):

try the unescaped operator:

```
li!= ...
```

it should do the trick.